# Converting fbx to gltf

Tags: c#, file-conversion

I have some fbx files were created by 3D Optitex 15.3.

I want to convert the files to glb files.

I can use 'Paint 3D' in Windows 10. However, I want convert them by C#.

Is there a way to convert .fbx file .glb file using c#?

Comment: Is `*.fbx` a corporate, binary file type? Or simply a renamed zip? What is `*.glb`?

Comment: You almost certainly need the FBX SDK to do this; could you use [FBX2glTF](https://github.com/facebookincubator/FBX2glTF)? (FBX and GLB are different 3D model file formats)